# SPS2010 - AD account password changing, for non-domain computers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, active-directory, ntlm

I have Sharepoint 2010 farm - application server(Sharepoint), database server(MS SQL 2008 R2), and domain controller. 3 servers total.

All of these 3 servers are included to domain(domain set up on 3-rd server), and Sharepoint works in NTLM authentication mode. All of users, works on non-domain computers, and they must enter AD login and password every time, they accessing SPS.

And, my question. If users works on non-domain computers, how they may change their AD account's password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main popular web parts for doing this is something like the Bamboo AD password changer for SharePoint (I'm not plugging them but it is the most popular web part for doing this)

http://store.bamboosolutions.com/pc-33-1-password-reset-web-part-release-12.aspx

http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-password-expiration-web-part.aspx

Comment: I'm found free solution at http://changepassword.codeplex.com/. @pigeon thanks for your link.

Comment: There are password change solutions from other companies too: [Harepoint](https://www.harepoint.com/Products/HarePointPasswordChange/Default.aspx), [Virtosoftware](http://www.virtosoftware.com/products/administration/virto-password-change)